# Plotly Dash: Clicking row_selectable in DataTable outputs a column value for that row in a Card component

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

The end goal is to be able to click a row in the datatable which outputs a column value of that row from the dataframe it is built from in a card component

I have a Datatable like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from dash import dash_table, Dash, dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


df = pd.read_csv(r"/home/me/Desktop/data.csv")

dash_table.DataTable(
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.loc[:,["Name", "age"]]],
               data=df.to_dict("records"),
               row_selectable="single",
               id="tbl_out"
               )
```

I only present few columns and would like to present a column value based on row clicked in a KPI card through row selected.

```
    dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H6("Probability of Default", className="card-title"),
                html.P("Some quick example text", className="card-text",),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    id="card",
),
```

I having trouble with the callback as the documentation for options concerning 'component_property' is sparse. This is what i tried so far:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="card", component_property="selected_rows"),
    Input(component_id="tbl_out", component_property="active_cell")
)

def display_click_data(active_cell):
    return active_cell
```

I know its a fairly simple problem, but its my first dash app!